# Extract a number in one column after - using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sas, data-cleaning

I want to extract whatever come after -

My data in column A looks like

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 001-3 | 5 |
| 002-14 | 6 |

what I want is

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001-3 | 3 | 5 |
| 002-14 | 14 | 6 |

Is there any function like scan for SAS in python, so I can extract the what come after "-" in column A and place it at column B, after move B to C

Comment: did the solution worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

```
# reassign Column B to Column C
df['Column C'] = df['Column B']

#split from right and limit to only single split, then take the right value to create column B
df['Column B']=df['Column A'].str.rsplit('-',n=1,expand=True)[1]
df
```

```
    Column A    Column B    Column C
0      001-3           3           5
1     002-14          14           6
```